# How to compare two LASSO models - is there an equivalent to AIC/BIC?

Tags: regression, model-selection, lasso, aic, model-comparison

It is often stated online that competing OLS models explaining a common dependent variable **y** can be compared by calculating an AIC or BIC for each fit, and that the model with the lowest value should be selected. This is also suggested as a way to justify whether including an additional variable in **X** is worthwhile, as the AIC/BIC of the model before and after the inclusion can be calculated and compared.

I'd like to do something similar for my problem. I have a set of 4 potential **X** variables that I would like to fit against my **y**. Because I want to investigate possible quadratic and interaction effects I actually need to fit *14* variables, and due to multicollinearity in my data I've opted to use a LASSO fit. In Python this is simple enough: use `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV` to find the best lambda value via cross-validation, and so the optimised fit. So far, so good.

But what if I want to assess whether adding another variable is worthwhile? Considering the same effects as above, my **X** now contains *20* variables, so I compute another LASSO fit. Calculating the RMSE and R2 against holdout data gives only a negligible difference (i.e. ~0.001 for R2) between the two LASSO models.

**Which model is the right one to use?**

I was wondering whether there was some way to compute the AIC/BIC for both LASSO models & to compare them, but I understand that this is not trivial. In Python `sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsIC` uses AIC/BIC to find the optimal lambda - could I use the AIC/BIC computed by this function to compare my two models?

Comment: If you're doing LASSO then you're doing some kind of out-of-sample testing, right?

Comment: The AIC and BIC are estimates of the expected test error computed using only a training data set. If you're using LASSO, you need some way of tuning the regularization parameter, which is usually (as mentioned by @Dave) done with cross validation or a fixed test set. So you generally directly estimate what AIC and BIC indirectly estimate.

Comment: @Dave: Matthew is correct, I am using cross-validation to tune the regularization parameter (lambda).

Comment: @MatthewDrury: So validation using holdout data takes precedence over AIC/BIC when comparing models? If there is no other way to compare these models, then I will report that it's impossible to determine if there is a significant advantage to using one over the other. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ElectronicAnt, you can calculate AIC and BIC for LASSO, I have seen it done in publications by reputable researchers. They do not even use cross validation for tuning, they use AIC or BIC to select the optimal tuning parameter. I do not have the time to write up a full answer now, but I will come back over the next couple of days if I do not forget. Feel free to ping me.

Comment: @RichardHardy: That's very interesting. Is the method used similar to ```sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsIC```? The user guide says that it's not recommended for high-dimensional data, but I'm not sure what the formal definition of that is. If I have ~20 variables and 30,000 observations, would LARS still be appropriate to use here?

Comment: @ElectronicAnt, I cannot confirm any rules of thumb as I have no personal experience with the method and have not its possible problems through. One clear advantage of IC instead of cross validation is computational time. Another is when cross validation is cumbersome, e.g. under dependent data such as time series.